# 10 bits a 8 bits en C

Tags: c

Mi duda es la siguiente:

Quiero crear una función a la que le pase como parámetro una velocidad en el rango de 0-1023 (10 bits) y tengo dos direcciones de memoria (de tamaño byte) referidas a la velocidad. La primera dirección estaría formada por los 8 bits de menos peso de este valor de velocidad y la segunda dirección serían todo ceros excepto los dos últimos bits, que serían los 2 bits de más peso de la velocidad.

Ejemplo aclaratorio por si me he explicado mal:

```
 velocidad = 774 --> 1100000110. 
 Primera dirección de memoria: 00000110
 Segunda dirección de memoria: 00000011
```

Además, como yo le paso el valor de velocidad en tipo `uint16_t` en formato decimal, ¿cómo podria obtener esto que necesito?

Expongo exactamente el problema a tratar para ver si se entiende algo mejor. Yo estoy trabajando con un micro MSP430 y un robot al que le quiero enviar una instrucción que lo mueve a una cierta velocidad, donde en el datasheet de dicho robot la velocidad se trata tal que así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, los bits del 15 al 11 siempre toman el valor de cero, luego el bit 10 sirve para seleccionar si quieres que se mueva en dirección horaria o antihoraria y del bit 9 al 0 para seleccionar el valor de velocidad (0-1023).

El problema radica en que estos 16 bits que conforman la instrucción en realidad son dos direcciones de memoria contiguas (los 8 bits de más peso en una dirección y los 8 bits de menos peso en otra dirección). Yo quería crearme una función en donde le pasara como parámetros la dirección de movimiento y la velocidad en un valor entre 0-1023, para luego descomponer estos dos datos y devolver un array formado por dos direcciones del estilo `0x20`, `0x30`.

> void velocidad(uint16_t velocidad_0_to_1023, uint8_t direccion){ // Se le >pasará una velocidad y una dirección: CW=1 o CCW=0 y te devuelva un array >estilo: array[2] = {0x20, 0x30};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad un dato de tipo `uint16_t` (que es lo mismo que `unsigned short int`) ya se almacena en memoria en la forma que dices, separado en dos bytes. Lo único que puede ocurrir es que, si la arquitectura es *little endian*, el byte que aparece primero tenga la parte baja y el que aparece después tenga la parte alta, o si la arquitectura es *big endian* ocurra lo contrario.

Cuando tú haces algo como esto:

```
uint16_t velocidad = 937;
uint8_t  direccion = 1;
uint16_t command = (direccion << 10) & velocidad;
```

en la variable `command` ya tendrías los dos bytes que necesitas. Si tratas de enviarlos a la dirección de memoria, digamos por ejemplo, `0xF0A0` mediante algo como lo siguiente:

```
uint16_t *direccion= 0xF0A0;
*direccion = command;
```

el puntero apunta en realidad a una dirección en la que caben 8 bits, por lo que cuando envíes los 16, éstos irán a direcciones consecutivas. En la dirección 0xF0A0 irá la mitad del dato, y en la siguiente, 0xF0A1, irá la otra mitad. Qué mitad va a cada dirección depende de la *endianity* de la máquina.

Si la arquitectura es *little endian*, la dirección 0xF0A0 recibirá la parte baja del dato, y la 0xF0A1 recibirá la parte alta. Si es *big endian* en cambio ocurrirá lo contrario.

Así que si tu arquitectura tiene la endianity adecuada para el dispositivo que recibe los bytes, no necesitas separarlos, basta enviarlos como un dato de 16 a la primera dirección, y el propio hardware de acceso a memoria lo separa y escribe en dos direcciones contiguas. Dependiendo del orden en que el dispositivo espere los bytes, podría funcionar directamente así. Si los espera en orden inverso, entonces puedes hacer uso de la función `htons()` para "darles la vuelta":

```
uint16_t *direccion= 0xF0A0;
*direccion = htons(command);
```

Comment: Vale, sisi. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes pasar un valor de dieciséis bits a dos valores de ocho bits así:

```
void u8_to_bin(uint8_t value)
{
    for (uint8_t i = 128u; i; i >>= 1)
        printf("%d", i & value ? 1 : 0);
    printf("\n");
}

void dieciseis_bits(uint16_t value)
{
    u8_to_bin((uint8_t)(value & 255u));
    u8_to_bin((uint8_t)(value >> 8u));
}
```

Suponiendo que tu [endianness](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) sea la que dices que es.

Si [pruebo con el valor `774`](https://tio.run/##fU9dS8MwFH1ufsWl4mhgunW4rVitf0HwVShpk80LXTLSZCDib683rWs3H4Q85BzO163v6kbofdfdoK4bLxU8tU6iuf8o2DWlXeDYyaAEn5XOlBXqxBNPAE6i8YqzLxbtjIWRRniGdJX5HJAeFAVBzqLoaEmwS@JbGc@Jnw1@eIEUHmHJczYq3nVM8Pu3WJq2rD6dascGMYfzt@r7p20i5EywusxBVWOrkNLQDWHp5uqMyXeu4skwcgar9dpznsNiAa8WD8qK//RFAVkvD/o3tfdaijCEVHAQZAiL@s4/q7bbBx9OsMp5q2FJ87vuBw) obtengo el resultado que buscas.

Comment: Me parece que lo que quiere es justo lo contrario. Tiene los dos bytes y quiere un solo número con los dos. Pero a ver que lo aclare, porque la descripción no se entiende bien.